# Safetensor model serving using pytorch torch serve container not starting

Tags: docker, pytorch, torchserve

I cannot start my saved safetensor model in my pytorch/torchserve container.

I can start my container using:

```
docker run --rm -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 --name test -v docker run --rm -it -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 -p 127.0.0.1:8081:8081 --name 805  -v C:\Users\.....t\output\TinyPixel\llama-42m:/home/model-server/model-store pytorch/torchserve:latest
```

I can enter the container, and the model directory is mounted.

```
model-server@ec5ebadcef2e:~$ ll

drwxr-xr-x 1 model-server model-server 4096 Nov 26 18:42 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 root         root         4096 Aug 28 21:07 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 model-server model-server  220 Feb 25  2020 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 model-server model-server 3771 Feb 25  2020 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 model-server model-server  807 Feb 25  2020 .profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root         root          246 Aug 28 21:01 config.properties
drwxr-xr-x 3 model-server model-server 4096 Nov 26 18:42 logs/
drwxrwxrwx 1 root         root          512 Nov 26 15:56 model-store/
drwxr-xr-x 1 model-server root         4096 Nov 26 18:42 tmp/

model-server@ec5ebadcef2e:~$ cd model-store/
model-server@ec5ebadcef2e:~/model-store$ ls
```

config.json  generation_config.json  model.safetensors  special_tokens_map.json  tokenizer.json  tokenizer_config.json

No model seems to be available but torchserve is running

```
$ curl  http://localhost:8081/models

{
  "models": []
}

model-server@ec5ebadcef2e:~/model-store$ torchserve
```

TorchServe is already running, please use torchserve --stop to stop TorchServe.

```
curl  http://localhost:8080/ping
```

{
"status": "Healthy"
}

```
 head -30 ts_log.log
```

2023-11-26T18:42:20,304 [WARN ] main org.pytorch.serve.util.ConfigManager - Your torchserve instance can access any URL to load models. When deploying to production, make sure to limit the set of allowed_urls in config.properties
2023-11-26T18:42:20,304 [WARN ] main org.pytorch.serve.util.ConfigManager - Your torchserve instance can access any URL to load models. When deploying to production, make sure to limit the set of allowed_urls in config.properties
2023-11-26T18:42:20,325 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.servingsdk.impl.PluginsManager - Initializing plugins manager...
2023-11-26T18:42:20,325 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.servingsdk.impl.PluginsManager - Initializing plugins manager...
2023-11-26T18:42:20,584 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.metrics.configuration.MetricConfiguration - Successfully loaded metrics configuration from /home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ts/configs/metrics.yaml
2023-11-26T18:42:20,584 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.metrics.configuration.MetricConfiguration - Successfully loaded metrics configuration from /home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ts/configs/metrics.yaml
2023-11-26T18:42:20,965 [INFO ] main org.pytorch.serve.ModelServer -
Torchserve version: 0.8.2
TS Home: /home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Current directory: /home/model-server
Temp directory: /home/model-server/tmp
Metrics config path: /home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ts/configs/metrics.yaml
Number of GPUs: 0
Number of CPUs: 12
Max heap size: 2964 M
Python executable: /home/venv/bin/python
Config file: /home/model-server/config.properties
Inference address: http://0.0.0.0:8080
Management address: http://0.0.0.0:8081
Metrics address: http://0.0.0.0:8082
Model Store: /home/model-server/model-store
Initial Models: N/A
Log dir: /home/model-server/logs
Metrics dir: /home/model-server/logs
Netty threads: 32
Netty client threads: 0
Default workers per model: 12
Blacklist Regex: N/A
Maximum Response Size: 6553500
Maximum Request Size: 6553500

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you